# Radgrid and RadFormDecorator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid, rad-controls

I have an ASP.NET application using the Telerik Q1 2009 controls. I have a masterpage, which has a FormDecorator control in the master page. In my ASPX page, I have a RadGrid, with the following definition:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridExclusions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                                    GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  PageSize="5">
                                    <MasterTableView>
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                                <ItemTemplate>                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEdit" Text="Delete"
                                                        CommandName="SelectSelect" CommandArgument='<%#GetEmployeeExID(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem")) %>'
                                                        />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Date" AllowFiltering="true">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#GetExDate(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Exclusion?" AllowFiltering="true">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#GetExclusionFlag(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Reason" AllowFiltering="true">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#GetReason(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Paid?" AllowFiltering="true">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#GetPaidStatus(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                    <HeaderContextMenu>
                                        <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
                                    </HeaderContextMenu>
                                    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                                    <FilterMenu>
                                        <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
                                    </FilterMenu>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

I also have a button that refreshes this radgrid:

```
Me.txtExcludeDate.Clear()
Me.gridExclusions.Rebind()
Me.txtExcludeDate.Focus()
```

The problem is, when I push the button to refrsh it, it works fine, except the button inside the radgrid seems to lose its Web20 Skin Look and Feel. It looks like a normal button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the RadGrid being updated? Is it using Ajax or full page refreshes?

If you're using Ajax (or, partial page updates), the RadFormDecorator can automatically re-skin the form elements, BUT you need to make sure you configure your DecorationZones correctly. Have a look at this demo to see if it helps:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/formdecorator/examples/partialpageupdates/defaultcs.aspx

Give that a try and see if it helps. If you can provide more information about what's happening when you click your buttons, that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does this discrepancy remain when you move to the Q2 2009 release of RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX? If so, it would be best if you report the issue in the Telerik forums or support system to get a patch for it.

Dick